# I was house robbed

Tags: theft

My house was robbed about a week ago (4 times in a row). It was a storage house; it had no power or electricity, but it was where I kept important stuff; well, I’m homeless. I had permission from my landlord. I found some of it a local pawn shop, but they won’t give it back, like they don’t believe me even though I showed photos of some of my stuff. What should I do?

Comment: This is more a matter of police procedure than law. A useful answer may also depend on the precise location, perhaps a specific city

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a legal issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Report the **theft** to the police. A **robbery** is something else in most jurisdictions.
- Report to the police that the pawnshop is selling stolen property. In most jurisdictions this is a crime if it is done knowingly.

Comment: He does now know he was told

Comment: @MasionSPouliot, some people lie, so being told is not knowing. That's why the police and courts need to look into this.